# Pass variable from one function to another

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to pass a URL and query string from one function to the other, as in the other function it captures the incorrect string, each time I try and pass it through to the second function it either captures the wrong query string or returns null.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'geturl');
function geturl($host) {
    
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    
    
        return $host;
    
    
         ob_start();                     // start buffer capture

    
    var_dump($host);
    
    
    
    

    $contents = ob_get_contents();  // put the buffer into a variable
    ob_end_clean();                 // end capture
    error_log($contents); 
    
    

}

/* Capture the string from the first function and change values based on the query string */

add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent','Kiri_cf7_api_sender');

 function Kiri_cf7_api_sender ( $contact_form) {
     
    $hosts = geturl('');
    echo $hosts;


                     ob_start();                     // start buffer capture

    
    var_dump($hosts);
    
    
    

    $contents = ob_get_contents();  // put the buffer into a variable
    ob_end_clean();                 // end capture
    error_log($contents);
```